# The difference between placement new operator and pmr in memory_resource?

Tags: c++, c++17, new-operator, c++pmr

In C++17 you can have a code like this:

```
char buffer[64] = {}; 
std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource 
     pool{std::data(buffer), std::size(buffer)};
std::pmr::vector<char> vec{ &pool };
```

We also have

```
char buf[64];
std::vector<char> *vect = new (buf) std::vector<char>;    // placement new
```

Both of the codes use some space in the stack. To me, it seems that new placement is excessive while memory_rsource can do much more. It was just an example on the stack but even if you want to have memory in the heap pmr will handle more conditions.

Is it an excessive definition in the standard? If I need to have a memory pool which one should I use? Which one handles exceptions better.

I have not found good tutorials on memory_resources and lots of stuff is ambiguous for me. Moreover placement new can not do much.

Comment: As far as I understand it new calls for memory from the os while memory allocators like pmr do handle memory they allocated for you. if you do manage of your memory I think pmr is better

Comment: @t.niese, I understand that. It seems unnecessary from the standard point of view

Comment: @justaguy, I agree with you. It makes the language ambiguous, though.

Comment: @NicolBolas Even the second vector is using the storage that is inside the buffer. Both of them are in stack

Comment: I am sorry. You are right. I didn't mean to have new there. I will update it

Answer (score 2):

> Is it an excessive definition in the standard?

No. It's the inevitable result of comparing a high-level tool to a low-level tool. Obviously, the high-level tool will use the low-level one.

Without placement-new (or equivalents like C++20's `std::construct_at`), it would be *impossible* to create objects within existing storage. That is, `polymorphic_allocator` will *use* placement-`new` (or an equivalent) internally.

It should also be noted that `std::memory_resource` is merely the way to allocate memory. Placement-`new` is how you create objects *within* accessible memory. They do completely different and unrelated things. This is why I said that it is `polymorphic_allocator`, not the `memory_resource` or any derived class, that uses placement-`new`.

`memory_resource`s are pure memory allocators, not object construction mechanisms. Container allocators combine object construction with memory allocation. As such, comparing

Comment: It is a good answer. Can you provide some references, please?

Comment: @Aznaveh: References for what? All of those are standard C++ types that you can search for if you need more specific information.

Comment: I want to see if the underlying code of pmr uses placement new. If you can point to the implementation.